# wrapping a dataview in a using statement produces bizarre results. Am I misusing the using?

Tags: c#, dataview, using-statement

This problem really baffeled me today.  I'm working in Visual studio 2012, C# .net 4 app (Not sure if it matters).

I have some datatables that have multiple results in them.  To figure out the best one to pick I'm looking for the one with the best Jaro-Winkler score, and sending that one back.
I sort the table results by making a dataview and in an attempt to properly dispose my data elements, I've wrapped the dataview in a using statment.  The code looks like this:

```
 public static DataRow getBestCandidate(DataTable searchTable, string searchName)
        {
            if (searchTable.Rows.Count == 1) //Nothing to do if there's only one row
            {
                return searchTable.Rows[0];
            }        

           int tableSize = searchTable.Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
                {
                        //Iterate through each entry and record the Jaro distance between our original search term.
                        searchTable.Rows[i][7] = jaro.getScrubbedDistance(searchTable.Rows[i][1].ToString(), searchName);
                }

                using (DataView dv = searchTable.DefaultView) //Sort the results
                {
                    dv.Sort = "JaroDistance desc";                 
                    return dv[0].Row; //Send back the result with the highest Jaro score.
                }          
        }
```

Here's what's weird.  The first time I call this, it works just fine.  Exactly as I want it to.
If I call it twice in a row from the same method, it almost works the second time.  When running a trace it gets all the way to the line "return dv[0].Row; " and when it goes to execute that, the object DV is null.  It behaves exactly like the object was disposed of before I was done with it. This ends up killing that thread with an exception.

I took out the using statement and replaced it with this:

```
 DataView dv = searchTable.DefaultView;
                    dv.Sort = "JaroDistance desc";

                    return dv[0].Row;
```

Then it works just fine.  Hammering the methods didn't seem to cause huge memory spikes.

Is the using wrapper even needed?  Why is it becoming null right before I return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `searchTable` is the same instance, you are disposing of its `DefaultView`, an object you are sharing each time you call the method.

The `using` isn't necessary here, but rather around `searchTable` in whatever parent method manages that object.